# Will push notification be collapsed if collapse_key not passed in payload?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options):

> If the device is connected but in doze mode, a low priority message is stored by GCM until the device is out of doze mode. And that's where the collapse_key flag plays a role: if there is already a message with the same collapse key (and registration token) stored and waiting for delivery, the old message will be discarded and the new message will take its place (that is, the old message will be collapsed by the new one). However, if the collapse key is not set, both the new and old messages are stored for future delivery.

I wanted to understand what will be the behaviour if `collapse_key` is not passed in the payload?

It is also mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#delivery_options):

> Except for notification messages, all messages are non-collapsible by default.

Does that mean all push notifications are  collapsible by default and user will get only one notification, if there are multiple messages sent to him when he is offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Except for notification messages, all messages are non-collapsible by default.

It's pointing out to `notification` message types (see [Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)). So technically, *not all* push notifications are collapsible by default. It depends on your payload.

If you use the `collapse_key` param in your payload with the same value each time, then yes, the expected behavior would be that only a single message with the same `collapse_key` is delivered (there is no guarantee which one though).

If you try sending a `data`-only message payload, each message would be delivered accordingly.